# Why a propertyChange of one string binded to a label do not rises if I set its value from other view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF application with two views and two model views in the View 1 there is a Button and a Label:

```
</WrapPanel>
<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Command="{Binding InitServerCommand}" Content="Connect to Server" Margin="10 10 0 0"/>
</WrapPanel>
<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Content="Info: " Style="{StaticResource myLabelStyle}"/>
<Label x:Name="lblInfoView" Content="{Binding Path=LblInfo, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource myLabelStyle}"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

And at the view model 1, I declarated the field lblInfo in this way:

```
     public class ViewModel1: BaseViewModel
        {
            public static string _lblInfo;
            public string LblInfo
            {
                get { return _lblInfo; }
                set
                {
                    if (_lblInfo != value)
                        _lblInfo = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("LblInfo");
                }
            }
    }
```

Additionally, I have a BaseView Model who extend INotifyPropertyChaged:

```
     public abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            protected BaseViewModel()
            {

            }

            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

And I have a function who do somenthing and refresh the value of LblInfo, that automatically maps on the Label in the View 1.

```
    public void send(string str)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Do somenthing
                    LblInfo = "Connect";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LblInfo = "Error..... " + ex.StackTrace;
                }
            }
```

The problem is:

If you call send() in the view model 1, automatically the program executes the setter and when it calls

```
OnPropertyChanged("LblInfo");
```

propertyChanged is different to null and it invokes

```
Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
```

And the View 1 succesfully update the Label content.

But if you call that method from the other model View 2

```
public class ViewModel2: BaseViewModel
  {
          public ViewModel1 ConfigureParametersVM
    {
        get { return GetValue<ViewModel1>(); }
        set { SetValue(value); }
    }
        //Constructor
          public ViewModel2()
    {
        ConfigureParametersVM = new ViewModel1();
        //Execute the send method from View Model 1
        ConfigureParametersVM.send("update_mroi");
    }

}
```

It runs the send method and the setter update the value for _lblInfo, but when it calls the OnPropertyChanged(), propertyChanged is equal to null and it doesn´t update the Label in the View1.

What I'm doing wrong?

Additional information

Right now, I dont have any mention of DataContext on the ViewModel1 or ViewModel2, could you tell me how can I do that? The code in the View1 (xaml) and (.xaml.cs) is this:                                                                                  .xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Namespace1.Views.View1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Namespace1.Views"
             xmlns:GuiControlLibrary="clr-namespace:GuiControlLibrary;assembly=GuiControlLibrary"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="1024">
    <Grid>
             //Somethin else        
            <Grid>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1">
                    <!--Code for TCP/IP Parameters-->
                     //More code not showed here
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            //This is the commad from Icommand that starts de method send()
                        <Button Command="{Binding InitServerCommand}" Content="Connect to Server" Margin="10 10 0 0"/>
                    </WrapPanel>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            //Static label
                        <Label Content="Info: " Style="{StaticResource myLabelStyle}"/>
            //Binded label
                        <Label x:Name="lblInfoView" Content="{Binding Path=LblInfo, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource myLabelStyle}"/>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the .xaml.cs is:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
namespace Namespace1.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for View1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class View1 : UserControl
    {
        public View1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add code showing how the DataContext of View1 is bound to the ViewModel1.

Comment: Take a look at your View1 xaml file. It sounds like you have ViewModel1 as a static resource.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code in your question:

```
public ViewModel2()
{
    ConfigureParametersVM = new ViewModel1();
    //Execute the send method from View Model 1
    ConfigureParametersVM.send("update_mroi");
}
```

The `ConfigureParametersVM` (ViewModel1) is not assigned as `DataContext` of a View.  Once it's assigned, the View will register for `PropertyChanged` events on the ViewModel.

Comment: Right now, I dont have any mention of DataContext on the ViewModel1 or ViewModel2, could you tell me how can I do that?

Comment: I already updated the question, including the code. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string _lblInfo;
```

This is dead wrong. It should be:

```
private string _lblInfo;
```

That won't solve your problem, but it will give a good hint why it does not work. Because you never called the send method of your view model instance. You created **a new one**. That's like having a second `int` and wondering why your first `int` does not change when you set the second one. Because they are different instances.

Your ViewModels need a way to know each other and without more code I cannot tell you what way might be best. But you need to connect the *existing* two instances, not create new ones.